# Unable to run desktop app on client side using local machine as server

Tags: php, laravel, server, phpdesktop

I have migrated my laravel based web app to a desktop app using phpdesktop. Everything is working fine when I am running it on my local. The problem arises when I tried to run it on the other machine using my machine as the server. Here's the code where I had made changes:-

```
"web_server": {
    "listen_on": ["XXX.XXX.X.XXX", XXXXX],
    "www_directory": "public",
    "index_files": ["index.html", "index.php"],
    "cgi_interpreter": "php/php-cgi.exe",
    "cgi_extensions": ["php"],
    "cgi_temp_dir": "",
    "404_handler": "/pretty-urls.php",
    "hide_files": []
}
```

In the above code I have mentioned my machine ip address and port number (in listen_on), but I was unable to run it on any other machine.

Comment: did you forward the ports in your firewall to allow external users to reach your app?why not use a hosting provider?

Comment: instead of "XXX.XXX.X.XXX", XXXXX , try localhost, 80 or 127.0.0.1, 80

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question above that it's working fine on local but I am getting trouble when I make my system as a server and use another machine as client@mark

Comment: it's firewall related issue. disable your firewall then try accessing http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX:XXXXX on your browser

Comment: I have forward ports in my firewall it's still not working and right now I am just giving a demo in my company, so I am not using any hosting service @madalinivascu

Comment: I have tried that it's still not working @mark

Comment: try to ping server ip address if you can ping it.

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to fix it. @Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue by making index.php file in www directory and writing a particular set of code in it

```
header('location:http://example.com/codeit/blackbolt/public/login')
```